# Travel arrangements with Sigma Lenses?

Tags: travel, nikon-d5100, sigma

I know there are a lot of threads on travel photography, I read some, but found that most are out of date, however, manufacturers kept innovating, and that starts to confuse a lot of newbies like me.

I'm going on a trip to Japan soon, and would like your advice, on which equipment to take with me, ideally I'd like to take at most two lenses with me. Let's start with what I already have, as I don't wan't to buy a new lens that overlaps what I already own:

- Nikon D5100
- The lens kit it came with: Nikkor 18-55mm 1:3.5-5.6
- Sigma Telephoto/Macro: 70-300mm 1:4-5.6 (No stabilization :S)

I was thinking about buying an all-in-one lens, or a [ultra] wide angle lens as I found myself having trouble shooting the *Cattedrale di Santa Maria del Fiore* on a past trip.

I did some research, but the Focus aspect of cameras still puzzles me (for me it's just a matter of how many planes one can shoot) so I would need some advice choosing between the lenses below, or possibly other lens brands/types that you would recommend for traveling (I can go up to $500, but would like something on the $350 range)

http://www.sigmaphoto.com/lenses/17-70mm-f28-4-dc-macro-os-hsm-c
http://www.sigmaphoto.com/lenses/18-200mm-f35-63-dc-macro-os-hsm-c
http://www.sigmaphoto.com/lenses/18-250mm-f35-63-dc-os-macro-hsm

It doesn't have to be Sigma, but the prices are good AFAIK, and the quality of the one I already have make me feel safe buying this brand.

Comment: **Welcome to Photo.SE.** This is a fine question, but as written it's off topic for this site because we avoid product recommendations, especially when they're bound to be short-lived or so specific that they only help one person. You might rephrase it to ask for help understanding the differences between the options you're interested in, if you're confused about that. But the best person to choose what's right for you is you. Be bold. Have a great trip.

Comment: I think this may cover your "how many planes one can shoot?" question — [How can I get everything in focus?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/4748/how-can-i-get-everything-in-focus) (Spoiler alert: just one, regardless of lens or camera.)

Comment: Ok, I think the main question here is:
I want to replace the lens kit my camera came with, so I can use it 90% of the times, and complement my experience with the telephoto I already have. Is buying a lens say 17-70 (as the telephoto is 70-300), a good move to make? I'm looking to have a lens that is wide enough for a big "scene", is the 18 and 17mm lens difference that big? Or it would make more sense to buy a ultra wide instead?

Comment: This question is too confusing. Why did you have trouble shooting the  Cattedrale di Santa Maria del Fiore previously? It is unlikely if a 18-55mm lens couldn't do it, that a 17-70mm could. Please explain.