# How is Focal Length defined for 180-degree fisheye lenses?

Tags: focal-length, fisheye

The definitions of Focal Length I saw seem to implicitly assume that the field of view is finite, which isn't true for 180-degree lenses, or presume parallel transport of certain rays passing through lenses, which is also not applicable. Thus I'm curious how Focal Length is defined for fisheyes.

Comment: The FoV for a 180° lens *IS* finite, even if the result of *R = f tanΘ* when Θ=180° is not. Collimated light (parallel rays striking the lens from a singular point source from a distance of infinity) *can* pass through a 180° fisheye lens and converge to a point behind the lens at a distance equal to the lens' focal length.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unlike "normal" (rectilinear) lens, [there are many types of fisheye lenses, using different projections](https://wiki.panotools.org/Fisheye_Projection). The same focal length (f) can give different image size and/or different distortions, depending on the type.

Example:

Assuming your 8mm lens uses the most basic equidistant fisheye (180° degrees field of view = -90°..+90°)

R = f · θ

8mm · π/2 ≈ 12.56mm

So, rays from -90°..+90° map to -12.56...+12.56mm on the image sensor or film, creating a 25mm circle. From calculation we can learn that such lens would not cover the 36x24mm full frame image area.

[image: Fisheye projections from https://wiki.panotools.org/Fisheye_Projection]

Comment: Note that in all cases the invariant fact is that dR=f·dθ in the center of the projection, i.e. when R=0 (with the exception of Thoby expression, where the focal length appears to be a senseless parameter).

Answer (score 3):

The parallel rays (collimated light) referenced in your question that are used to determine focal length are rays that all originate from a *single point source of light* at a [distance of infinity](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/93587/15871) from the camera, not from all of the infinite number of different points within the lens' field of view. This is just as true for a very long focal length telephoto lens as it is for a very wide angle lens.

For a 'perfect' lens, collimated rays from any point source at a distance of infinity within the field of view will converge at a distance behind the lens equal to the focal length of the lens. Thus, **focal length is the distance behind the lens at which collimated light striking the lens will converge.**

For compound lenses (lenses with more than one lens element with real thickness - pretty much every modern photographic lens), the distance a theoretical thin lens having the same refractive properties would need to be in front of the focal plane for collimated rays striking that lens to converge to a point is used as the lens' focal length.

No lens is perfect, though. Most of the time rays from the edge of a lens' FoV don't converge as sharply as rays from the center of the optical axis do. This can be particularly the case with wide angle lenses that attempt a rectilinear projection. Fisheye lenses, which can have one of several different projections, give up a rectilinear projection that preserves straight lines in exchange for fewer aberrations at the edges of the lens' field of view.

Infinity does *not* refer to the lens' field of view (the angle between the camera and two objects that a lens can show in opposite corners), it refers to a distance away from the camera's [focal plane](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/45970/15871) at which light from a single point source will strike every point on the surface of the lens as collimated light (parallel rays) and converge back to a point at a distance behind the lens equal to the lens' focal length.

It seems you are confusing ray diagrams that show rays of light from a single point source striking every part of the front of the lens with diagrams that show the range of angles with which light can strike a lens and be included in the image it projects at the rear of the lens. The two types of diagrams are showing entirely different properties of a lens. The first shows various rays from a single point source of light that (hopefully) converge back to a single point behind the lens. The second shows the range of angles from which  light can strike a lens and be included in the lens' field of view.

Comment: I wasn't talking about imperfections of real lenses by rather about the inconsistency of the usual definitions of focal length *f* when applied to 180 degree fisheye lenses. Specifically, the *f* for usual lenses can be derived from their projection formula, *R = f tan theta*, which makes no sense when *theta = 90*. As @szulat explained in his answer, the projection formulas for fisheye lenses are different from the usual lenses.

Comment: @Michael This answer is not primarily about the imperfections of real lenses. It is about the way terms used in the question are properly defined. If the result of a formula is an irrational number when a specific angle is used, that does not mean that the angle used to get that result equals infinity. That's the main point of this answer. A lens with a 180° FoV does *not* have an *infinite* FoV. Also, *any lens* with a FoV of *any angle* can be focused at *infinity* if it can converge collimated light to a point at a specific distance behind the lens.

Answer (score 1):

To mount an extreme wide-angle, the optician will likely choose a retro-focus design.  You might want to know that the focal length is a measurement of the distance from the rear nodal of the lens to the film or digital image sensor, when an object at infinity is sharply defined.

To make a wide-angle, the focal length is short thus the distance lens-to-film/sensor is contracted. Now the optician is forced to make a retro-focus lens.

A retro-focus design is actually an inverted telephoto. This strategy creates a longer than normal back focus distance (lens-to-sensor). In other words, the retro-focus design shifts the lens barrel forward allowing more room for mirror swing and mounting hardware.

The retro-focus design is accomplished by grinding the up-front lens group concave, this gives negative power i.e. divergent lenses. The rear grouping is ground strongly positive (convergent). The two groups work together to deliver a wide-angle with an elongated back focuses distance.  This asymmetry causes barrel distortion. The good news is, an extreme wide-angle can now be accommodated.

Comment: Thanks for the description of the optical system design, but could you add a **definition** of what Focal Length **is** that would be applicable to extreme wide angle lenses? For example, what 8 mm and 15 mm refers to in the description of Cannon 8-15mm Zoom Fisheye lens that has 180 degree view angle?

Comment: @Michael The 8-15mm Fisheye is a *zoom* lens, It can only be at a single focal length between 8mm and 15mm at any given time, depending on the position of the various lens elements based on the position of the zoom ring.

Comment: A lens with extreme angle of coverage. The geometry of a conventional lens allows delivery of undistorted image up to about 120°. For 180° coverage, extreme retro-focus design with barrel distortion permitted. Two versions a. quasi-fisheye fills the format and delivers 180° diagonal angle of view. True fisheye delivers circular image that does not fill the frame. Focal length = rear nodal to image. Fisheye is an equidistant projector where image height = focal length multiplied by the angle of coverage. Convention lens  image height = focal length multiplied by tan of the angel.